# Android app - free RAM to run

Tags: android, ram

I was wondering why my app won't run on my friend's phone. 
I've checked RAM Usage of my app and I found out, that it needs ~180Mb to load all bitmaps. So I have few questions:

- Is it possible to run app which needs 180Mb RAM on phone that in moment of running has ~130Mb free RAM?
- 180Mb RAM usage, while loading few images (150kb one) is ok or too much?

Comment: `while loading few images (150kb one) is ok or too much?` **obviousy it not depends on their "on disk" size ...** ... *I was wondering why my app won't run on my friend's phone*  ... then just try... Where is the question?

Comment: `Is it possible to run app which needs 180Mb RAM on phone that in moment of running has ~130Mb free RAM?` - my main problem. Another one: Is it possible to force phone to clear RAM so my app can run?

Comment: *Is it possible to force phone to clear RAM* yes, dispose the unnecesery bitmaps and gc would do this ...

Comment: Thanks, another one: `Will my app run when phone in moment of running do not have enough RAM?`

Comment: gc = garbage collection. Let's be new user friendly :)

Comment: *Will my app run when phone in moment of running do not have enough RAM?* obviously it will throw OOMException as in any other language or OS

Comment: _obviously it will throw OOMException as in any other language or OS_ - So is it possible to force phone to run it? GC on my app start would change something?

Comment: its too much ,,,,! let me share the code which prevent from this crash ...

Answer (score 0):

> I've checked RAM Usage of my app and I found out, that it needs ~180Mb to load all bitmaps.

On many devices, if not most devices, your app does not have rights to have 180MB of heap space. There is a per-app heap limit, set in the device firmware. That could be as low as 16MB, though 32-64MB is commonplace on all but the lowest-end devices. But 180MB would be unusually large.

While there are ways that your app *might* be able to have a ~180MB heap (e.g., `android:largeHeap`), there still will be plenty of devices where you will not get that much heap space.

Note that the heap limit is independent of how much free RAM there is at the moment on the device. It does not matter if the phone has ~13MB free RAM, ~130MB free RAM, or ~1.3GB free RAM — the heap limit is the heap limit.

I strongly encourage you to reduce your heap usage, ideally by a factor of 10 or so.

> Is it possible to run app which needs 180Mb RAM on phone that in moment of running has ~130Mb free RAM?

Probably. Android will terminate other processes to free up system RAM for yours, assuming that your app is in the foreground at the time. This may include terminating some processes that the user would prefer *not* be terminated.

> 180Mb RAM usage, while loading few images (150kb one) is ok or too much?

IMHO, it is far too much.

Comment: Thank you for this informations, i had no idea about it

Answer (score 0):

Yep 150kb image is too much .... you need to make it resized so that the android allocate the memory according to requirement. It prevents from OOM app crash.

```
int resolution=100;
    profileImageViewNav.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.profile_image, resolution, resolution));
```

Here is decodeSampledBitmapFromResource() function

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

And Here is calculateInSampleSize() function code

```
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I'm already using those functions and still same problem.